# Copy value of character array and initialize to integer?

Tags: arrays, c, string, integer, converters

**What I'm trying to do:**
I have an array of characters, something that looks like "vm1". I would like to set an integer variable equal to the value of the last element of the array, in this case 1. I don't need anything fancy, as the length of the array in my case will always be 3.

**My code:**

```
char *string = "vm1";
int number = (int)string[2];

printf("Character from string: %c", string[2]);
printf("Number: %d", number);
```

**Output:**

```
Character from string: 1
Number: 55
```

**What is going wrong:**
For some reason, the number is always some incorrect value. 55 was just from this case. Another method I tried was using `sscanf` but it produces similar results.

Comment: If it is always a single digit, you can do `string[2]-'0'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the ASCII value of the character to the actual decimal number. To do so you have to use:

```
int number = string[2];
number = number - '0';
```

Why is that? If you search for an ASCII table you will find that the character `'1'` corresponds to a decimal value of 49, so if you subtract the ASCII value of `'0'` (48) you get the right decimal result, 1.